# XSLT adding new element to current node

Tags: xslt, element, addition, parent

I have a xml and I am trying to add a new element then assign the value on certain conditions.
Everything is working fine.
However, it seems to adding the new element to the parent node.
Can someone help me figure out the issue.

Below is the full **XSLT**. But I am having problem with the last template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id[. = '']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../following-sibling::ns0:Broker[1]/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Cedent/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. = '']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Agency">DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Reinsurer[not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id != '') and not(ns0:Reinsurer/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. != ''])]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Reinsurer/ns0:Contact[not(ns0:PersonName !='')]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Reinsurer/ns0:Contact/*[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Broker/ns0:Contact/ns0:Telephone[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ServiceProvider[. = '6']" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ServiceProvider[not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id != '') and not(ns0:Reinsurer/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. != ''])]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Contract/ns0:ContractGroupName[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Endorsement[ns0:Placing/ns0:PlacingStage = 'endorsement']" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Endorsement/ns0:EndorsementReference[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Endorsement/ns0:EndorsementName[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Endorsement/ns0:Description[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Endorsement/ns0:EffectiveDate[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:BrokerSharePercentage[not(node()) and ns0:ContractSection/ns0:BrokerSharePercentage/ns0:Rate > 0]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:RiskLocation[not(node()) or (ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'request_for_line_or_binder' or ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'signed_line_advice' or ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'quotation_request' or ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'endorsement_request')]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:RiskLocation/ns0:Location/ns0:Supraentity[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:RiskLocation/ns0:Location/ns0:Country[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:PerilsIncluded[not(ns0:Peril/ns0:PerilType !='')]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:Brokerage[descendant::ns0:Rate = '' and not(ns0:ContractSection/ns0:BrokeragePercentage/ns0:Rate > 0)]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:ContractMarket/ns0:Reinsurer[descendant::ns0:Id = '' and not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. != ''])]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:ContractMarket/ns0:ReinsurerContractReference[not(node())]" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:ContractMarket/ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage[descendant::ns0:Rate = '']" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:ContractMarket/ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage[descendant::ns0:Rate = '' and ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'signed_line_advice']" />

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Placing">

    <xsl:variable name="percentage-rate" select="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:OrderPercentage/ns0:Rate"/>

    <xsl:copy>
      <ns0:ContractSection>
      <ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'signed_line_advice' and $percentage-rate > 100"/>
      </ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:ContractMarket"/>
      </ns0:ContractSection>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Source XML:**

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace">
    <ns0:Placing Sender="broker" Receiver="serviceprovider">
        <ns0:UUId>GUID</ns0:UUId>
        <ns0:BrokerReference>2B3B8992-3185-48EE-A030-0F61EFF7C7EB</ns0:BrokerReference>
        <ns0:ServiceProviderReference>16</ns0:ServiceProviderReference>
        <ns0:PlacingStage>order</ns0:PlacingStage>
        <ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction>signed_line_advice</ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction>
        <ns0:TransactionReasonDescription></ns0:TransactionReasonDescription>
        <ns0:Cedent>
            <ns0:Party>
                <ns0:Id Agency=""></ns0:Id>
                <ns0:Name>Bahamas First General Insurance Co/Aon Benfield Canada</ns0:Name>
            </ns0:Party>
        </ns0:Cedent>
        <ns0:Reinsurer>
            <ns0:Party>
                <ns0:Id Agency=""></ns0:Id>
                <ns0:Name>RI3K</ns0:Name>
            </ns0:Party>
            <ns0:Contact>
                <ns0:PersonName>test</ns0:PersonName>
                <ns0:Telephone></ns0:Telephone>
                <ns0:Email>test@ri3k.com</ns0:Email>
            </ns0:Contact>
        </ns0:Reinsurer>
        <ns0:Broker>
            <ns0:Party>
                <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">292320710</ns0:Id>
                <ns0:Name>Aon Benfield UK</ns0:Name>
            </ns0:Party>
            <ns0:Contact>
                <ns0:PersonName>Jenny Edwards</ns0:PersonName>
                <ns0:Telephone>reinsurance_contract</ns0:Telephone>
                <ns0:Email>jenny.edwards@aonbenfield.com</ns0:Email>
            </ns0:Contact>
        </ns0:Broker>
        <ns0:ServiceProvider>
            <ns0:Party>
                <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">239195295</ns0:Id>
            </ns0:Party>
        </ns0:ServiceProvider>
        <ns0:Contract>
            <ns0:ContractName>FINCO QUOTA SHARE TREATY</ns0:ContractName>
            <ns0:ContractGroupName>BFG FINCO QUOTA SHARE TREATY</ns0:ContractGroupName>
            <ns0:ContractType>0</ns0:ContractType>
            <ns0:BrokerReference>B110813BDO1053</ns0:BrokerReference>
            <ns0:BrokerGroupReference>200153436</ns0:BrokerGroupReference>
            <ns0:BrokerRiskReference>13BDO1053</ns0:BrokerRiskReference>
        </ns0:Contract>
        <ns0:Endorsement>
            <ns0:EndorsementReference>0</ns0:EndorsementReference>
            <ns0:EndorsementName></ns0:EndorsementName>
            <ns0:Description></ns0:Description>
            <ns0:EffectiveDate></ns0:EffectiveDate>
        </ns0:Endorsement>
        <ns0:ContractSection ContractReportingLevel="section_level">
            <ns0:HighLevelReference>01</ns0:HighLevelReference>
            <ns0:CoverType>quota_share</ns0:CoverType>
            <ns0:ContractPeriod>
                <ns0:StartDate DateIndicator="Jan  1 2013 12:00AM"></ns0:StartDate>
                <ns0:EndDate DateIndicator="Dec 31 2013 12:00AM"></ns0:EndDate>
            </ns0:ContractPeriod>
            <ns0:UnderwritingYear>Jan </ns0:UnderwritingYear>
            <ns0:ContractSectionClass>
                <ns0:JvClassOfBusiness>wind_storm_unspecified</ns0:JvClassOfBusiness>
                <ns0:ClassOfBusinessDescription>wind_storm_unspecified</ns0:ClassOfBusinessDescription>
            </ns0:ContractSectionClass>
            <ns0:RiskLocation>
                <ns0:Address>
                    <ns0:Country></ns0:Country>
                </ns0:Address>
                <ns0:Location>
                    <ns0:Supraentity></ns0:Supraentity>
                    <ns0:Country>BS</ns0:Country>
                </ns0:Location>
            </ns0:RiskLocation>
            <ns0:PerilsIncluded>
                <ns0:Peril>
                    <ns0:PerilType></ns0:PerilType>
                </ns0:Peril>
            </ns0:PerilsIncluded>
            <ns0:ContractAmountsCurrency>
                <ns0:Ccy>GBP</ns0:Ccy>
            </ns0:ContractAmountsCurrency>
            <ns0:BrokerSharePercentage>
                <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">2.500000</ns0:Rate>
            </ns0:BrokerSharePercentage>
            <ns0:OrderPercentage>
                <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">41.000000</ns0:Rate>
            </ns0:OrderPercentage>
            <ns0:Brokerage>
                <ns0:BrokeragePercentage>
                    <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">2.500000</ns0:Rate>
                </ns0:BrokeragePercentage>
            </ns0:Brokerage>
            <ns0:ContractMarket>
                <ns0:Reinsurer>
                    <ns0:Party>
                        <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">239195295</ns0:Id>
                    </ns0:Party>
                </ns0:Reinsurer>
                <ns0:ParticipantFunction>leader</ns0:ParticipantFunction>
                <ns0:ReinsurerContractReference></ns0:ReinsurerContractReference>
                <ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage>
                    <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">100.000000</ns0:Rate>
                </ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage>
                <ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage>
                    <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">100.000000</ns0:Rate>
                </ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage>
            </ns0:ContractMarket>
        </ns0:ContractSection>
    </ns0:Placing>
</ns0:Root>
```

**XML output:**

```
  <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace">
  <ns0:Placing Sender="broker" Receiver="serviceprovider">
    <ns0:UUId>GUID</ns0:UUId>
    <ns0:BrokerReference>2B3B8992-3185-48EE-A030-0F61EFF7C7EB</ns0:BrokerReference>
    <ns0:ServiceProviderReference>16</ns0:ServiceProviderReference>
    <ns0:PlacingStage>order</ns0:PlacingStage>
    <ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction>signed_line_advice</ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction>
    <ns0:TransactionReasonDescription />
    <ns0:Cedent>
      <ns0:Party>
        <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">292320710</ns0:Id>
        <ns0:Name>Bahamas First General Insurance Co/Aon Benfield Canada</ns0:Name>
      </ns0:Party>
    </ns0:Cedent>
    <ns0:Broker>
      <ns0:Party>
        <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">292320710</ns0:Id>
        <ns0:Name>Aon Benfield UK</ns0:Name>
      </ns0:Party>
      <ns0:Contact>
        <ns0:PersonName>Jenny Edwards</ns0:PersonName>
        <ns0:Telephone>reinsurance_contract</ns0:Telephone>
        <ns0:Email>jenny.edwards@aonbenfield.com</ns0:Email>
      </ns0:Contact>
    </ns0:Broker>
    <ns0:ServiceProvider>
      <ns0:Party>
        <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">239195295</ns0:Id>
      </ns0:Party>
    </ns0:ServiceProvider>
    <ns0:Contract>
      <ns0:ContractName>FINCO QUOTA SHARE TREATY</ns0:ContractName>
      <ns0:ContractGroupName>BFG FINCO QUOTA SHARE TREATY</ns0:ContractGroupName>
      <ns0:ContractType>0</ns0:ContractType>
      <ns0:BrokerReference>B110813BDO1053</ns0:BrokerReference>
      <ns0:BrokerGroupReference>200153436</ns0:BrokerGroupReference>
      <ns0:BrokerRiskReference>13BDO1053</ns0:BrokerRiskReference>
    </ns0:Contract>
    <ns0:Endorsement>
      <ns0:EndorsementReference>0</ns0:EndorsementReference>
    </ns0:Endorsement>
    <ns0:ContractSection ContractReportingLevel="section_level">
      <ns0:HighLevelReference>01</ns0:HighLevelReference>
      <ns0:CoverType>quota_share</ns0:CoverType>
      <ns0:ContractPeriod>
        <ns0:StartDate DateIndicator="Jan  1 2013 12:00AM" />
        <ns0:EndDate DateIndicator="Dec 31 2013 12:00AM" />
      </ns0:ContractPeriod>
      <ns0:UnderwritingYear>Jan </ns0:UnderwritingYear>
      <ns0:ContractSectionClass>
        <ns0:JvClassOfBusiness>wind_storm_unspecified</ns0:JvClassOfBusiness>
        <ns0:ClassOfBusinessDescription>wind_storm_unspecified</ns0:ClassOfBusinessDescription>
      </ns0:ContractSectionClass>
      <ns0:RiskLocation>
        <ns0:Address>
          <ns0:Country />
        </ns0:Address>
        <ns0:Location>
          <ns0:Country>BS</ns0:Country>
        </ns0:Location>
      </ns0:RiskLocation>
      <ns0:ContractAmountsCurrency>
        <ns0:Ccy>GBP</ns0:Ccy>
      </ns0:ContractAmountsCurrency>
      <ns0:BrokerSharePercentage>
        <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">2.500000</ns0:Rate>
      </ns0:BrokerSharePercentage>
      <ns0:OrderPercentage>
        <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">41.000000</ns0:Rate>
      </ns0:OrderPercentage>
      <ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>false</ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
      <ns0:Brokerage>
        <ns0:BrokeragePercentage>
          <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">2.500000</ns0:Rate>
        </ns0:BrokeragePercentage>
      </ns0:Brokerage>
      <ns0:ContractMarket>
        <ns0:Reinsurer>
          <ns0:Party>
            <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">239195295</ns0:Id>
          </ns0:Party>
        </ns0:Reinsurer>
        <ns0:ParticipantFunction>leader</ns0:ParticipantFunction>
        <ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage>
          <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">100.000000</ns0:Rate>
        </ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage>
        <ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage>
          <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">100.000000</ns0:Rate>
        </ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage>
      </ns0:ContractMarket>
    </ns0:ContractSection>
  </ns0:Placing>
</ns0:Root>
```

The problem I'm having is with `<ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>` node
It should fall under `<ns0:ContractSection>` instead it is coming under parent node of `<ns0:ContractSection>` which is `<ns0:Placing>`

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide a complete (but small) source XML document. Also provide a complete transformation (if possible, small). In its current state, this isn't a real question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Good catch. Sorry about the oversight. I have added the stylesheet and a sample xml. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: Is this *"XML output"* what you *require*, or is it what you are currently getting that needs fixing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet seems to do what you need, although some points are unclear.

Note that the string value of a boolean expression is either `true` or `false`, so since that's what you want you can just use `value-of` instead of `choose` / `when` / `otherwise` as I have done here. I've also pulled out the value of the order percentage rate into a variable so that the expression isn't too ungainly.

Since the new `LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator` element depends on both `PlacingTransactionFunction` and `OrderPercentage/Rate` I assume that's why both these original elements are missing from the output, so I've coded it that way. But I'm not clear why the `ReinsurerContractReference` element isn't in your desired output, and if that's a mistake then all you need to do is to remove the final template that matches just this element and it will be reinstated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:Placing">

    <xsl:variable name="percentage-rate" select="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:OrderPercentage/ns0:Rate"/>

    <xsl:copy>
      <ns0:ContractSection>
        <ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
          <xsl:value-of select="ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'signed_line_advice' and $percentage-rate > 100"/>
        </ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:ContractSection/ns0:ContractMarket"/>
      </ns0:ContractSection>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:ReinsurerContractReference"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://somenamespace">
   <ns0:Placing>
      <ns0:ContractSection>
         <ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>false</ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
         <ns0:ContractMarket>
            <ns0:Reinsurer>
               <ns0:Party>
                  <ns0:Id Agency="DUNS_dun_and_bradstreet">239195295</ns0:Id>
               </ns0:Party>
            </ns0:Reinsurer>
            <ns0:ParticipantFunction>leader</ns0:ParticipantFunction>
            <ns0:ReinsurerContractReference/>
            <ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage>
               <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">100.000000</ns0:Rate>
            </ns0:ReinsurerQuoteMaximumSharePercentage>
            <ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage>
               <ns0:Rate RateUnit="percentage">100.000000</ns0:Rate>
            </ns0:ReinsurerWrittenPercentage>
         </ns0:ContractMarket>
      </ns0:ContractSection>
   </ns0:Placing>
</ns0:Root>
```

---

**Update**

In addition to what you already have, you need a template for `OrderPercentage` that adds the new `LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator` immediately after copying itself.

This should do the trick.

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:OrderPercentage">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ns0:Placing/ns0:PlacingTransactionFunction = 'signed_line_advice' and ns0:Rate > 100"/>
  </ns0:LinesPercentageOfOrderIndicator>
</xsl:template>
```

I note that you have numerous ways of checking whether an element is empty. There is

- `not(node())`, which is "has no children"
- `element = ''` which evaluates the element as a string
- `not(element != '')` which is the same, but more confusing!

For the latter two to work you need to strip any insignificant spaces from the text nodes, either using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` at the top of the stylesheet, or by using `normalize-space` on the value in the test. But it is neatest to use the fact that an expression evaluates to `false` if it is the empty string, so you can just write `not(element)` to test if it is empty.

In addition you have these

```
ns0:Reinsurer[not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id != '') and not(ns0:Reinsurer/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. != ''])]
```

and

```
ns0:ServiceProvider[not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id != '') and not(ns0:Reinsurer/ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency[. != ''])]
```

which look like they should be

```
ns0:ServiceProvider[not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id or ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency)]
```

and

```
ns0:ServiceProvider[not(ns0:Party/ns0:Id or ns0:Party/ns0:Id/@Agency)]
```

because it is nice to lose the double negatives, and there is no `ns0:Reinsurer` child of either a `ns0:Reinsurer` element or a `ns0:ServiceProvider` element. (It isn't clear from you data that `ns0:ServiceProvider` can have any children at all, but obviously I can't be sure.)

Comment: I've tried to plug in this but didn't work. Because I didn't put the full version of XSLT and XML. So clear out the confusion I have uploaded the full XSLT and XML.

Comment: @JohnXsl: OK I have added to my solution to provide you with a simple additional template that will fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and your suggestions. Sorry I got busy with other stuff and didn't get a chance to implement your suggestions yet. I will integrate your suggestions and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Excellent solution and explanation. Thanks for your help